# How could I resize this image without misplacing pixels?

Tags: ffmpeg, image-editing, image-processing, resizing

I wanna resize an upscaled 1366x768 image down to its native 480x270 again.

Every time I do it, lines of pixels are misplaced. [Example with highlighted areas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiqfl.png) The image on the right is slightly out of frame, but the differences are clearly visible.

I tried using variations of the following command to no avail:
`ffmpeg -i "imagepath" -q:v 1 -vf scale=480:-1 -sws_flags neighbor "outputpath"`

Some advice on what's going on and how I could resample it down without misplacing columns and rows of pixels would be much appreciated.

[This is the image in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzHdz.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results are normal, because your input size is not an exact multiple of your output size – it is not an exact downscale like 3-to-1 but more like 2.85(ish)-to-1; so eventually there *will be* output pixels that only correspond to e.g. 2 or 4 or 3½ input pixels and have to be stretched or compressed.

The provided image seems to have 3×3 "large pixels" (dots? cells? squares? I don't know of a good term), so if you claim the original was 480×270, this means it was actually upscaled to 1440×810 and then *cropped* to fit 1366×768. So the recoverable original is only 456×256.

(To see this visually, open the file in GIMP, select "Enable grid", "Configure grid", choose 3×3px. Note that vertically it doesn't even have an integer amount of "large pixels"; the leftmost and rightmost columns are only 2px wide and cause everything to be offset from the grid.)

So what you'd need to do is:

1. Pad or crop the image so that both dimensions are multiples of 3 (the "large pixel" size). The vertical size is already good, but horizontally you must pad by 1px left & right – this will also realign the columns to grid. I used GIMP's "Canvas Size" because I don't know ffmpeg filters.
2. Scale down to **456:256** or 456:-1 because that's the actual data you've got – the rest had been cropped away. I used your ffmpeg command for this.

Here's the result:

[image: Output image]

Comment: Huh. I'd never have known. I really appreciate the help, thanks a lot.